# Sticky Section Header RecyclerView using Flexible Adapter?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop an app with Sticky Section Headers with Desired Item Numbers. **I skimmed various tutorials and samples. I found the Flexible Adapter is most suitable. But I cannot find any tutorial or Sample that describes how can implement this** in my App. I can't understand the codes and descriptions in the GitHub Repo.

This is what I aims.

```
Fruits    3 items     ---- Section Header
  Mango
  Apple
  Orange
Animals     5 items     ---- Section Header
  Cat
  Rat
  Elephant
  Rabbit
  Got
```

I have to add header in any desired position between the whole 8 items.

Please help.....

**This is the sample**

[image]

Comment: check this out .https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view

Answer (score 1):

In `FlexibleAdapter` library you don't create your own adapter, instead you create your item and extend it with `AbstractFlexibleItem` and then pass a list of items to `FlexibleAdapter`.

First create your Item object with`AbstractFlexibleItem`

```
public class YourItem extends AbstractFlexibleItem<YourItem.MyViewHolder> {}
```

[see complete Item example in the doc](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter/wiki/5.x-%7C-Setting-Up)

Then just get a list of your items and just pass it to the adapter:

```
List<IFlexible> yourItems = getListOfItems();

FlexibleAdapter<IFlexible> adapter = new FlexibleAdapter<>(yourItems);

recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now if you want to create sections then simple create a section item just like normal item and add it to the data list. section item will be defined as follow:

```
public class YourHeader
        extends AbstractHeaderItem<YourHeader.HeaderViewHolder>
        implements IFilterable<String> {}
```

[see complete header item example in example file](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter/blob/master/flexible-adapter-app/src/main/java/eu/davidea/samples/flexibleadapter/items/HeaderItem.java)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement “One RecyclerView + Multiple type ViewHolder(view)” scheme, then you must implement

**getItemType** in adapter class.

in this method, you can handle item type with position from parameter.

in **onCreateViewHolder**, you can take type with second parameter, and just make another ViewHolder.

Comment: I have only less experience with android studio and Flexible Adapter. can u explain ?

Comment: @Koyas It is not hard. You can make two ViewHolder class and can use these for one adapter.  You can decide which view holder will be used with Type, Position in above methods.   You can get detail information in this article.  https://link.medium.com/Mgxt1wT0wX

Comment: it is great. but I think u don't care about my question. I need Sticky Section header with child items in desired position. And also need its detailed instructions.

Answer (score -1):

Try ExpandableListView to expand for sub-items of each Header.